# bootstrap button on click showing default colour

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, colors

I am trying to style the button colour with below code, the colours work until I click the button, the button shows the default colours, how do I specify the colours of the button onclick?

```
.btn-success { 
 color: #ffffff; 
 background-color: #161617; 
 border-color: #494F57; 
} 

.btn-success:hover, 
.btn-success:focus, 
.btn-success:active, 
.btn-success.active, 
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-success { 
 color: #ffffff; 
 background-color: #1F2838; 
 border-color: #494F57; 
} 

.btn-success:active, 
.btn-success.active, 
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-success { 
 background-image: none; 
} 

.btn-success.disabled, 
.btn-success[disabled], 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-success, 
.btn-success.disabled:hover, 
.btn-success[disabled]:hover, 
 fieldset[disabled] .btn-success:hover, 
.btn-success.disabled:focus, 
.btn-success[disabled]:focus, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-success:focus, 
.btn-success.disabled:active, 
.btn-success[disabled]:active, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-success:active, 
.btn-success.disabled.active, 
.btn-success[disabled].active, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-success.active { 
background-color: #161617; 
border-color: #494F57; 
} 

.btn-success .badge { 
  color: #161617; 
 background-color: #ffffff; 
}
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The `:active` selector is what you need for the click.

```
.btn-sample:active {
  // click styles here
}
```

It looks like you have that above so if you are still seeing a slightly different color it is most likely because of the `box-shadow` that is also applied to the `active` button state. Disable that like so:

```
.btn-sample:active {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Edit:
The selector that is overriding your css is actually `btn-success:active:focus`. So you will need to add the following to your css:

```
.btn-success:active:focus {
  color: #ffffff; 
  background-color: #161617; 
  border-color: #494F57;
}
```

Further to my comment below, you would be better off creating your own class such as `btn-custom` to which you can apply your desired styles. Combining this with the existing `btn` class, you can achieve your desired result with much less code as you won't need to override existing selectors.

Comment: it changes to the green success colour, Ive updated the code in the question to btn-success, should I be creating new button from scratch instead of trying to override the success button?

Comment: I have updated my answer as I discovered an overriding selector. In regards to creating a new button from scratch, it would be better if you were to create a `btn-custom` class and add the styles you wanted to that as this would not require the overrides but still benefit from the standard `btn` class

Answer (score 35):

You have to use the `!important` declaration to do that correcly.

```
.btn-success:hover, .btn-success:active, .btn-success:focus {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  background-color: #1F2838 !important;
  border-color: #494F57 !important;
}
```

Comment: `!important` did it for me. For some reason, mouse-down on the button still used the default styles.

Comment: !important is the cheapest and quickest way to the goal, the problem though, is that this can quickly get messy after further complicating your styles later, there's no such thing as !even-more-important

Comment: @Prof83, right! At that point you just start adding !important to everything and adding extra unneeded ID and class selectors to existing selectors to raise the specificity and after that just start inlining CSS, What could possibly be wrong with that approach. 

Comment: I also had to add a `box-shadow` property for .`btn-success:focus` along with `!important`.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this behaviour with this css code:

```
.btn-primary {
    background-color: #8ed3cc;
    border: 0 !important;
    padding: 1rem 5rem;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: #69aca5 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
 }
 .btn-primary:focus {
    background-color: #69aca5 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Some inspiration from the [bootstrap source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/295c93846c154fb461f85b30e663102f7e171104/scss/mixins/_buttons.scss) for overriding these various button states where $off-white and $brand-black are defined by us:

```
.btn-success {
  &:hover,
  &:focus,
  &.focus {
    color: $off-white;
    background-color: $brand-black;
  }

  &:active,
  &.active,
  &.disabled,
  &:disabled {
    color: $off-white;
    background-color: $brand-black;

    &:focus,
    &.focus {
      color: $off-white;
      background-color: $brand-black;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That button press animation of the default color is due to the background image. Use this for each named style (btn-default, btn-success, etc):

```
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code in your CSS

```
.btn-success.active.focus, .btn-success.active:focus, .btn-success.active:hover, .btn-success:active.focus, .btn-success:active:focus, .btn-success:active:hover, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-success.focus, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-success:focus, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-success:hover
{
color: #fff;
background-color: #161617; 
border-color: #494F57; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a personal project, and not with a team, it is worth noting that you can override pseudo class styles simply by applying "!important" to the same style declarations on the class:

`.btn-success { 
  color: #ffffff !important; 
  background-color: #161617 !important; 
  border-color: #494F57 !important;
}`

Generally, it's a good idea to stay away from !important because this will override any and all color, background-color and border-color style declarations on the btn-success class (unless you override the style declarations again with !important later in your style sheet although that's ridiculous).

If the goal is the smallest file size possible though and you are using this class everywhere in the same way - meaning no inline styles - then this may be your best option.

Alternatively, but using the same thinking, you may try naming a new custom class something like .btn-success-important, and only apply it after btn-success where you need to use the override.

There is one catch though: If you are combining .btn-success or your .btn-success-important with any other Bootstrap .btn-group, !important will override any pseudo class style declared within.  In this case you may be better off with Guy's answer (the custom class without !important style declarations).

Answer (score 0):

if you want remove the box-shadow just add box-shadown:none and make it important or if you want add box-shadows just add color values.

```
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5b5fc6;
    border-color: #5b5fc6;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

or

```
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #5b5fc6;
        border-color: #5b5fc6;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem #c9cbfa !important
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to trigger any class whenever a button is clicked, you need `:active` selector and to fix the default behavior of the bootstrap button on click, you need to set the `background-color` to any color you want to along with `!important`. It will then override the default styling of the bootstrap class.

```
.btn-outline-primary:active{ background-color: [your color] !important}
```