# How to change the button color after it has been pressed?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Project in question:https://vecissitude.github.io/landing-page/

I am building this landing page as a project and I am having an issue with the button. Once you press it,the browser takes you to a new page. If you hit back you go back to starting page but the color of the button changes to blue. That was the original color from the Bootstrap component that I changed to orange on the style sheet.

How can I change the color after button has been pressed? I figure it has something to do with the :active pseudo-class so I typed this code in the style sheet which did nothing. Any help is appreciated.

```
.btn-primary:active {
     background-color: rgb(255, 68, 0) !important;
     border-color:rgb(255, 68, 0) !important;
     border-width: 5px;
          }
```

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379175/bootstrap-button-on-click-showing-default-colour

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

This is called `:focus`

> The :focus selector is used to select the element that has focus.
>
> Tip: The :focus selector is allowed on elements that accept keyboard
>   events or other user inputs.

Here is an example

```
.btn-primary:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0069d9;
    border-color: #0062cc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(38,143,255,.5);
}
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus